# Does there exist a non-constant solution to this (and other similar) functional equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

It started where the expression $\frac{1-x}{x^2}$ came up, and in thinking to simplify the system of equations, I thought there might be a substitution I could make: "what if there is a constant $a$ such that, for $h(x) = \frac{1-x}{x^2},$ $h(x-a) = \pm \frac{1}{x-a}$?"

Well, this didn't quite land because in such an assumption, if I solve for the $+,$ then I derived that the result was still dependent on $x$, that $1 = 2x - 2a.$ If I took $-,$ then I derived $1=0.$

Pretty dismal so far, but now I'm wondering whether there exists an $f(x)$ such that

$$h(f(x)) = \frac{1}{f(x)}?$$

You can plug $f$ into $h$ and equate the two but this only finds constant solutions. How do I know there isn't some elementary or implicitly elementary or gamma-function-like integral, non-constant function that satisfies

$$\frac{1-f(x)}{f(x)^2} = \frac{1}{f(x)}?$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1-f(x)}{f(x)^2}
&= \frac{1}{f(x)}
\\
\frac{1}{f(x)^2}-\frac{1}{f(x)}
&= \frac{1}{f(x)}
\\
\frac{1}{f(x)^2}
&= 2\frac{1}{f(x)}
\\
f(x)^2
&= \frac{f(x)}{2}
\\
f(x)
&= \frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I appreciate you attempting to answer joseville, but please read the last line and preceding paragraph. I'm aware constant solutions exist, what I don't know is whether non-constant solutions, as a function of $x,$ also exist.

Comment: @StackQuest You misunderstand. $f(x)=\frac12$ is derived from the problem condition, so this proof shows that it is the only solution.

Comment: The derivation would have been easier if you multiplied through by $f^2(x)$ at the start.